# Android: Is there a way to obtain altitude aside from Location.getAltitude()? (I've heard using Sensor)

Tags: android, android-sensors, altitude

Is there a way to obtain altitude aside from Location.getAltitude()?
I've heard using Sensor but don't have idea and can't find on net.

**UPDATES1**
I found `SensorManager.getAltitude(float, float)` using API Level 9 up but don't have idea on how to implement it. Would you share with us.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late but for anyone looking for it, that might help

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor sensor;
    private float altitude = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (sensor != null) 
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float presure = event.values[0];
        altitude = SensorManager.getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE, presure);

        System.out.println("altitude => " + altitude);
    }
}
```

Comment: This totally works but I am still unsure why Location.getAltitude() always returns 0...?