# Android: Where is the SensorEvent's values for TYPE_PRESSURE?

Tags: android, android-sensors, pressure

I've read this documentation -> [SensorEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

then, I found that in order to get the values for TYPE_PRESSURE sensor type, I need to listen for SensorEventListener.

The problem is the documentation for TYPE_PRESSURE sensor's values is missing.
Anyone knows it?

**UPDATES1**
I previously created questions that may relate on this matter. Would you take a look also these links: [Obtain Altitude value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410095/android-is-there-a-way-to-obtain-altitude-aside-from-location-getaltitude-i) & [SensorManager.getAltitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411114/android-how-to-use-sensormanager-getaltitudefloat-p0-float-p)

Comment: android phones with pressure sensor (barometer) are very rare, are your sure you want this type of sensor? or do you need the pressure someone apply to the display in an touch Event?

Comment: @Michele I need the value from that sensor to do my main goal. which is to obtain altitude using SensorManager.getAltitude(float, float). but don't know how to obtain the values of the two float parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the WSP url and post another question on how to read the result. Eventually, I found the answer too.

Here's the url to obtain the Pressure At Sea Level value to pass on SensorManager.getAltitude as parameter.
[Obtaining Pressure At Sea Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549603/gis-how-to-read-metar-taf-values-to-get-the-pressure-at-sea-level)

Then, the second parameter Atmospheric Pressure may be obtained via `event.values[0]`. I came up this from @Marioo O. Lenci 's idea.

Answer (score 2):

from the [getAltitude reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getAltitude%28float,%20float%29) i guess you can use `SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE` as first parameter.

the second parameter is the value that the pressure sensor give you. To get it, i haven't tried i'm just guessing, you probably have to register a [SensorEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html) with [SensorManager.registerListener(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29).

Normaly the values in the `SensorEvent` object are in the `event.values` attribute so even if there is not any documentation try to take a look at the values stored in there.

If you have a divice that will let you do it will be easy.
if not check the [emulator documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#console) that probably include a way to fire the pressure sensor by the ADB

Comment: 1) Yes I can use the PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE but there is a note for accuracy, that's why I am searching a way not to use it. 2) That is the problem, I don't have the device for that as of now but need to know the arrangement of event.values[]. Like the other sensor documentation.

Comment: try to take a look at this if you want to simulate the pressure sensor:
http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator .
I took a look at the emulator renference( http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#console ) and it seems there are no ways to simulate sensors trought telnet.

Comment: The first parameter to getAltitude is the pressure at sea level. Using the constant PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE is very much a first aproximation.  It is this first parameter that you change to callibrate for real atmospheric pressure.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the value of this constant then it is:

```
public static final int TYPE_PRESSURE = 6
```

It's defined here: 
[android.hardware.Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_PRESSURE)