# Sensor's returned value is always 0

Tags: android, user-interface, sensors

I implemented a class in java (Android) to calculate the device's altitude and I want to access to this value from an another class.

The first class is as follows:

```
public class DeviceAltitudeHandler extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

SensorManager sm;
Sensor sensor;
float altitude ;


public DeviceAltitudeHandler(SensorManager sm, float altitude) {
    super();
    this.sm = sm; 
    this.altitude = altitude;
    sensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);
    sm.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI); 

}




@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float [] values = event.values;
    altitude = SensorManager.getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE,values[0]);

}

public float getAltitude() {
    return altitude;
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

public void start() {
    sm.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

}


public void stop() {
    sm.unregisterListener(this);
}

}
```

I am using a real smartphone that integrates a barometer but the returned value is always 0 !!! and the code of the second class is:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;
DeviceAltitudeHandler dah;
float altitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Service.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    dah = new DeviceAltitudeHandler(sm,altitude);

    tv.setText(""+dah.getAltitude());

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    dah.start();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    dah.stop();

}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default you `altitude` value initialized with `0` and you are changing this value in the `onSensorChanged` which is called when sensor values have changed but you are trying to output it inside `onCreate` when `onSensorChanged` possibly haven't been called yet and you are receiving your initial value `0`.

Try to add logs inside `onSensorChanged` method and check if it is called and which value its return.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The problem is with the method onSensorChanged, is not called and the returned value is always 0 (the initial value).

Comment: In fact, the problem is with "getAltitude()" method, it doesn't return the altitude value.

Comment: @Wima you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410095/android-is-there-a-way-to-obtain-altitude-aside-from-location-getaltitude-i and compare with your code maybe you made some mistake

Comment: @Wima have fixed your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Have you fixed the problem?